# How to connect via SSH to the console, which is currently active and displayed on the server monitor (Ubuntu)?

Tags: linux, ssh

There is a server to which the monitor is connected, how can I control this console through a connection via ssh?

[The picture shows an example of what I want.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kgLaC.png)

Comment: Solved: type "tmux" on server, and "tmux attach" in ssh connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you cannot.

It is possible to do some *limited* operations, i.e. use `writevt` to send fake input and `peekvc` to grab the output, but it is not possible to actually "reattach" a tty from one terminal to another (if you were imagining the way Remote Desktop works).

- If you can prepare upfront: Run your program in a *multiplexer* such as tmux, Screen, abduco, or dtach. Now the program can be attached on the console, *and* you can attach via SSH as well without detaching it from the console.
- If you didn't prepare, and the program is already running: Download [peekvc](http://0pointer.de/lennart/projects/peekvc/) and [writevt](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/grawity/code/master/thirdparty/writevt.c). Use peekvc to grab a "screenshot" of the console, and send keypresses via writevt if necessary. Requires root.

Comment: Thanks!

I launched a "tmux" on the server as user, and after connecting via ssh, I write a "tmux attach" and monitor displays the same as in the console ssh.